# Clipping raster is taking too long in 3.16.0-Hannover

Tags: qgis, gdal, clip

Okay so I wanted to clip [this][1] raster with this [JPN_adm0.shp][2] file. It's been more than 6 hours and it's still on "Processing algorithm part."
I have a decent PC that has 12GB of RAM 1TB NVME SSD and 6GB of DDR6 GPU. I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong on my part.

Here's the log file:

```
QGIS version: 3.16.0-Hannover
QGIS code revision: 43b64b13f3
Qt version: 5.9.5
GDAL version: 2.2.3
GEOS version: 3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6
PROJ version: 493
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Clip raster by mask layer' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : '/home/rez/Downloads/Japan Merged.tif', 'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : True, 'MASK' : '/home/rez/Downloads/JPN_adm/JPN_adm0.shp', 'MULTITHREADING' : False, 'NODATA' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : '/home/rez/Desktop/Japan Clipped.tif', 'SET_RESOLUTION' : False, 'SOURCE_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'), 'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'), 'X_RESOLUTION' : None, 'Y_RESOLUTION' : None }

GDAL command:
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of GTiff -tr 0.00027777777777777783 -0.0002777777777777778 -tap -cutline /home/rez/Downloads/JPN_adm/JPN_adm0.shp -cl JPN_adm0 -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata 0.0 "/home/rez/Downloads/Japan Merged.tif" "/home/rez/Desktop/Japan Clipped.tif"
GDAL command output:
Creating output file that is 111794P x 77320L.

Processing input file /home/rez/Downloads/Japan Merged.tif.
```

The input file is 1.3 GB but the output file is currently 4.3 GB and still processing. What should I do to improve the clip processing time? Should I try using GDAL on cmd?
[1]: https://mega.nz/file/bygC2ZrY#f9qVhTLILM6B_0QxIOSV7z3v-_gPhC09pz1dH18iLfQ
[2]: https://mega.nz/folder/n6gklJDQ#tAlU-G6a5ak6J4ZaVlyYhA

Comment: Also how do I set 'MULTITHREADING'  to True?

Comment: Please provide details (preferably a `gdalinfo` report) of the input raster.